# MongoDB Shell does return value but my code doesn't

Tags: mongodb, meteor

If i am typing in my console, i am getting the result of two entrys.
[image: Concole result]

but trying to get some data in my code fails.

```
let test = {};
    test.entry =  Posts.find().count();
    console.log(test.entry);
```

that returns 0!

My Collection:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Did i forget about something?

**Problem solved**.
forgot to publish / and subscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let test = {};
test['entry'] = Posts.find().count();
console.log(test.entry)
```

Comment: @user3553562 did you remove autopublish from packages? if yes, did you do pub/sub? I tested my answer and it works like a charm. If you're trying that in console, write test.entry alone, without the console.log()

Answer (score 0):

[Posts.find().count() is asynchronous](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#count) and should have a callback parameter.

try using

```
Posts.find().count(function(err, count) {
  test.entry = count;
  console.log(test.entry);
});
```

This should be ok for testing, but you will obviously have to check for `err` as well when you are implementing it in production :)

Comment: test.entry with ur method returns "undefined"

Comment: @user3553562 how are you checking? remember, it is async, so `console.log(test.entry);` must be inside the function. I am editing the answer to make it more clear :)

Comment: hmm, now it returns nothing, no new line in my console :/

Comment: looks like it isn't going into the method body

Comment: What mongodb driver and version are you using?

Comment: finally got it in another answer

Comment: i just forgot to publish and subscribe :/, but thanks for helping that fast!

Comment: @user3553562 oh, ok! please add it to this question or mark it here as duplicated :)